# Kaparos with fish

Tags: minhag, fish, communities, kaparot

In [How to do kapparos with fish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48633/how-to-do-kapparos-with-fish) it discusses doing Kaparos with fish. Is anyone aware of any group or individuals that do Kaparos with fish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Alsatian associate told me that the custom of Alsatian Jews is to perform kapparot with a fish.