# Do fish feel pain?

Tags: jewish-books, animals, fish, tzaar-baalei-chayyim, psychology

Are there any seforim, esoteric or otherwise, that teach such matters as the physiological differences between various species or general categories of animals? For example do fish feel pain?

If they do then why do we let them flop about and asphyxiate once out of the water which could be taken to indicate suffering?

(To clarify what I’m really most curious about: the nature of the souls of various animals and how they each experience the world. My curiosity was aroused regarding fish specifically as I read a scientific article discussing the matter which pointed out amongst other things that people have a tendency to project human traits onto animals. Another point was that fishing and avoiding “noxious stimuli” doesn’t prove they feel pain. Personally, I would be inclined to believe that dolphins for instance have a capacity for physical and emotional pain while some fish have more simple systems.

Another reason I'm curious about this is that in “tract on prayer” by the rebbe Rashab in the eighth section, it is stated: “similarly a behema which doesn’t have daas doesn’t feel a wound or pain as much like a person does (but nonetheless feels some due to the koach hamidameh within the creatures neural system”))

Comment: Even if they didn't, it's hard to imagine they wouldn't feel some distress at being out of the water. But who's to say it's worse than other forms of death?

Comment: All animals feel pain. Certainly with the cessation of their life.

Comment: @Ionlyknowgenesis welcome to Mi Yodeya. I think the question would be improved if you provide context. Is this related to tzaar baalei chayim, to killing methods, or differences with animal souls, etc.

Comment: I added some context. My interest lies in the souls of the animals.

Comment: Yes. Although my question is also a general question regarding what seforim may discuss these issues of animal physiology or spiritual makeup.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! The scientific journal Biology and Philosophy [published](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4356734/):

> The alternative view that fish instead respond to noxious stimuli
> reflexly and with a limited behavioural repertoire is defended within
> the context of our current understanding of the neuroanatomy and
> neurophysiology of mental states. Consequently, a set of fundamental
> properties of neural tissue necessary for feeling pain or experiencing
> affective states in vertebrates is proposed. While mammals and birds
> possess the prerequisite neural architecture for phenomenal
> consciousness, it is concluded that fish lack these essential
> characteristics and hence do not feel pain.

And a biomedical researcher [writes](https://www.wellbeingintlstudiesrepository.org/animsent/vol1/iss3/1/):

> Here I delineate the region of the human brain that is directly
> responsible for feeling painful stimuli. The principal structural
> features of this region are identified and then used as biomarkers to
> infer whether fish are, at least, anatomically capable of feeling
> pain. Using this strategy, I conclude that fish lack the necessary
> neurocytoarchitecture, microcircuitry, and structural connectivity for
> the neural processing required for feeling pain.

There will likely continue to be two sides of this fence as it is difficult to pinpoint whether fish feel pain or are just reacting to dangerous stimuli. Nonetheless, it is certain that the psak that we are not [required to shecht](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/why-do-fish-not-need-shechita) fish will continue to be true. (The fact that tzaar baalei chaim [does not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/tzar-balay-chaim-for-fish?rq=1) apply to fish seems to imply that Chazal understood that fish don't feel pain the way that it would be an issue.)

Comment: Other than your final paragraph, how is this a Jewish answer?

Comment: @Dov In order to make the last paragraph more palatable to a wider audience, I thought quoting researchers who say fish do not feel pain would help bolster Chazal's approach.

Comment: That may be the case, but the whole point of Mi Yodeya is to bring sourced Jewish answers.